# How to use cv2.triangulatePoints with a single moving camera

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

I have a single camera that I can move around. I have the intrinsic parameter matrix and the extrinsic parameter matrix for each camera orientation. For object detection, I use YOLO and I get 2D bounding boxes in the image plane. My plan is to use a temporal pair of images, with the detected object in it, to triangulate the midpoint of the resulting 2D bounding box around the object.

Right now, I use two images that are 5 frames apart. That means, the first frame has the object in it and the second frame has the same object in it after a few milliseconds. I use cv2.triangulatePoints to get the corresponding 3D point for the 2D midpoint of the bounding box.

My main problem is that when the camera is more or less steady, the resulting distance value is accurate (within a few centimeters). However, when I move the camera around, the resulting distance value for the object starts varying quite a bit (the object is static and never moves, only the camera looking at it moves). I can't seem to understand why this is the case.

For cv2.triangulatePoints, I get the relative rotation matrix between the two temporal camera orientations (R = R2*R1) and then get the relative translation (t = t2 - R*t1). P1 and P2 are the final projection matrices (P1 for the camera at an earlier position and P2 for the camera at a later position). P1 = K[I|0] and P2 = K[R|t], where K is the 3x3 intrinsic parameter matrix, I is a 3x3 identity matrix, and 0 is 3x1 vector of zeros.

Should I use a temporal gap of 10 frames or is using this method to localize objects using a single camera never accurate?

Comment: The method should work IMHO. Would it be okay for you to explain a bit more about the "resulting distance value"? Is it the reprojection error?

Comment: The distance value is the distance of the center from the camera in the first frame. I get the center in the reference frame of the camera that is 5 frames before but since the camera is moving all the time, I bring all 3D coordinates into the reference frame of the camera in the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

The centers of the bounding boxes are not guaranteed to be the projections of a single scene (3d) point, even with a perfect track, unless additional constraints are added. For example, that the tracked object is planar, or that the vertexes of the bounding boxes track points that are on a plane. Things get more complicated when tracking errors are present.

If you really need to triangulate the box centers (do you? are you sure you can't achieve your goals using only well-matched projections?), you could use a small area around the center in one box as a pattern, and track it using a *point* tracker (e.g. one based on the Lucas-Kanade algorithm, or one based on normalized cross-correlation) in the second image, using the second box to constrain the tracker search window.

Then you may need to address the accuracy of your camera motion estimation - if errors are significant your triangulations will go nowhere. Bundle adjustment may need to become your friend.

Comment: The objects I am trying to localize are very small. So, the midpoint of the 2D bounding box in frame 1 is not so far away from the midpoint of the same object in frame 5 (or even frame 10). Shouldn't the 3D coordinates (obtained in the reference frame of the first frame), be significantly close?

Comment: Also, just to verify, I use frame n and frame n-5 to localize the 2D bounding box's midpoint in the reference coordinates of frame n-5. To get the localization in the reference coordinates of frame 1 (the very first frame), I use the same method I used to get the projection matrices for the camera at frame n and frame n-5.

Comment: Hard to tell at this point without looking at your imagery and tracks. The chaining of the camera poses is simple math, only advice I'd have there is that, when chaining long-ish sequences (e.g. > 10 frames) you should avoid multiplying rotation matrices, or re-orthogonalize periodically - best practice is to use quaternions.